# Paypal Payments in Dirham using mobile sdk

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

How to make android application accept paypal payment in UAE dirham using mobile sdk?

I tried using

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(
                        Float.parseFloat(totalPrice)), "AED",
                        "CheckOut",
                        PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
```

It gives error

Comment: Can you tell us what error it throws?

Answer (score 0):

The mobile sdks are based on the REST APIs. Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/ for the currencies and countries supported. It does not seem like AED is a supported one unfortunately.

Comment: Your best bet might be to open a ticket with paypal merchant technical  support, this seems like a good starting point https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/merchant